# Asynchronous Upload of Large File Using HttpWebRequest in C#.Net

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I want to upload a large file in asynchronous  way using HttpWebRequest.

Say i upload a audio file  from using HttpWebRequest  & on the receiver end it should get the stream & play the audio file.

Is there any code or example availabel for ref. ?

Please provide if any example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Break this down into individual pieces and work on them (and ask questions as you go).  As it stands, the question is too broad to provide a concise, good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use HttpWebRequest and assuming your input data stream is not large you can make the upload process Async by doing this.  Notice the BeginGetResponse is what actually opens the connection to the remote server and processes the upload.

```
public void UploadAsync()
{
    var data = GetStream("TestFile.txt");

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://example.com/UploadData"));
    request.Method = "POST";
    data.CopyTo(request.GetRequestStream());

    request.BeginGetResponse(DataUploadCompleted, request);

    Console.WriteLine("Upload Initiated.");
}

private void DataUploadCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
    var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar);
    Console.WriteLine("Upload Complete.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but in my case the file is a large audio file. Can i use this for that?

Comment: Sure you can load any data as long as it is a Stream.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a `HttpWebRequest`?  You can do this very easily with the `WebClient` object

```
public void UploadFile(byte[] fileData)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.UploadDataCompleted += client_UploadDataCompleted;
    client.UploadDataAsync(new Uri("http://myuploadlocation.example.com/"), fileData);
}

void client_UploadDataCompleted(object sender, UploadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }

    byte[] response = e.Result;
}
```

Comment: Yes it have to be HttpWebRequest!!!