# Dropbox file extension missing after upload of Revit file using UploadAsync()

Tags: c#, upload, filestream, dropbox-api, revit-api

I am uploading a file with a .rvt extension. using filestream  and then UploadAsync(). I can upload and download the file from a folder I generate on the Dropbox remote server using a c# desktop app called from a winform. I can also rename the file with the correct extension and it is formed correctly. below is the code to achieve that. How can I rename the file or create the file correctly on dropbox so it has the correct extension? The properly formed file is of little use without an extension ".rvt".

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open(localPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (fileStream.Length <= ChunkSize)
            {
                await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(remotePath, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: fileStream);
            }
```

The next issue is if I try to upload a file say 24mb or greater using the same code it returns an error?

cheers.

Comment: If you have another issue, open another post with the specifics, such as the error message.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file to Dropbox, it will have whatever file extension you specify, but you do need to specify it yourself.

In your code, the `remotePath` value should be the entire path and name, including file extension, you want for the uploaded file. For example, to upload a file "myfile" with extension "rvt" to a folder named "myfolder", the value should be "/myfolder/myfile.rvt".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to upload a large file using C# appears to be via a `WebClient` object:

[Asynchronous Upload of Large File Using HttpWebRequest in C#.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775296/asynchronous-upload-of-large-file-using-httpwebrequest-in-c-net)